# What is the format of the optionsFile for the IotFDevice class in Quarks?

Tags: iot, apache-edgent

The IotfDevice Class in Quarks has a constructor with an optionsFile.  What is the format of this file and what are the necessary values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options file has five values: org, type, id, auth-method, auth-token. This is an example of mine with the values obfuscated.

```
[device]
org = 4pj4r4
type = rustQuark
id = rustIIa
auth-method = token
auth-token = 8jLWEY(P4SVJl5oi!V
```

When you register a device the set of values are issued, details and examples can be found [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/index.html#iot170).

**A little context.**

Internet of Things Foundation (IoTf) is an infrastructure for application's to communicate with devices. IoTf requires that you register the application and all
devices that send data to the application.

Why would you use IoTf? Getting the communication setup between devices is 
a pain: firewalls, retry, failover, QoS, debugging, monitoring. This is   facility especially nice if you're doing a proof of concept.

For a better description of IoTf look [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/index.html).